How can Neo see the future in his dream about Trinity?
Neo dreams of Trinity falling from the building and risking death. We see that later that exact circumstance takes place. How could Neo dream of the future?
Neo talks with the Oracle about this:

Neo: I see Trinity, and something happens, something bad. She starts
to fall, and then I wake up.
The Oracle: Do you see her die?
Neo: No.
The Oracle: You have the sight now, Neo. You are looking at the world
without time.
Neo: Then why can't I see what happens to her?
The Oracle: We can never see past the choices we don't understand.
Source

I have no problems with the extent of what he can and cannot see relative to his understanding of choices (Oracle's last line), but just how does it happen? I would guess that there is something more to read between the lines than just "You have sight now, Neo".
I've searched for (neo dream trinity), (neo future trinity) and (neo dream future) but couldn't find an answer

Trinity does an awful lot of jumping off of things in a most inadvisable way. It's hardly a leap of the imagination to envision that she might fall to her death; https://youtu.be/aLbdfgY_IhM?si=8NTL0v03H26mFk3S&t=160

@Valorum lol true, she does have fun in the Matrix. Yet reality resembles Neo's dream perfectly, so this is not about a safe assumption of Trinity risking death any other day

What's really going to bake your noodle is that the Architect literally has footage of her falling to her death on his screens, several minutes before it happens; https://i.sstatic.net/6HXM37pB.png

@Valorum Cool, never noticed it but that's not a problem for me: at that point Neo had already had the dream many times. It's not a stretch to assume that machines have been able to read it (if anything once Neo enters the mainframe) and display it. Unless you think that explains something of how Neo does see that?

Philosophically - our future is decided by the choices we make and the actions that come from those choices. Beings that are aware of your choices - and the choices of others - can play the consequences of those actions forward, there by getting a glimpse of the future. The Architect has complete awareness of what's happening in the Matrix, of the choices being made, so can extrapolate what's going to happen. He accurately predicts what Neo will do, because Neo has already made that choice.
Practically  - The Matrix is a running program/many programs, applying logic to data. the Architect can see the trends in the data, and can extrapolate from the trends what's going to happen. This currently happens in the real world, people monitoring large software systems can see that "Component A" is using more resources than usual because it's getting hit more often by users, better spin up a second copy/instance and balance the load between them. Power stations monitor the temperature of spinning turbines, and shut them down before there's a catastrophic failure.
Whichever way you want to look at it, Neo - due of his role as "balancer of the equation" - either has some aspects of powers of both the Oracle and the Architect or can access their powers. He does this intuitively, at a subconscious level, therefore he experiences prescient dreams about Trinity and her potential demise.

There is the physical concept that time as a dimension is actually not so different from the space dimensions. In a lot of physical calculations and theories you can actually replace time with an additional space dimension and everything still makes perfect sense, sometimes it even makes theories easier to comprehend. A prominent example being Einsteins relativity theory.
A important implication of this concept is that we as humans simply experience time in a uniform way moving ever forward through it. You could think of it as of reading a book. All the words are there all the time. It is just the reader that reads each word one at a time from the beginning to the end and experience it as a story. The way the reader experiences it does not change the fact that every word in the book is THERE. Even if you just opened the book, the end is already there, and the reader reaching that end does not make the beginning of the book a past thing. The beginning is also still there.
Just like that, according to said concept, all moments of time are also there all the time. It is just that we (the reader) experience one moment after each other but all moments are there all the time. From the big bang to the heat death of the universe.
If that concept is true, it would be possible to see through time just like you can look along a hallway. When you stand in a hallway you can see what is on the other side without actually being there. The things a the end of the hallway don't suddenly pop into existence when you go there. They are also there all the time, no matter where you are in the hallway.
This concept also matches with the philosophical concept of a "predetermined universe" and therefor clashes with the concept of "free will". If everything and all happens at once it is implied that no one can change anything about it, while free will would be exactly that.
In "Matrix" it seems to me like a "lite" version of this concept is true. Not every moment from the big bang to the heat death is "there" and "predetermined" but a shorter timeframe. Namely the timeframe up to the point where neo could interfere by making a decision. So in this example the hallways has doors which neo can't see past until he is there or at least until he made a decision on which door he will open.
This also fits neatly with the "the world is a simulation" aspect of matrix. In a simulation you could also calculate the future up to the next outside interaction but not beyond. However, depending on the complexity of the decision, you could calculate multiple ways the things play out.
You could compare this with a game of chess where one player has the other in check. As long as the player with the upper hand can force each move they can accuratly calculate the next move of the player in check even before any move has been made. Up until the move where no more forced moves can be made and the player in check regains his "free will"
